# Error in ViewPager in Fragments

Tags: java, android

Error shows in this line:  mPageAdapter = new PageAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments); and Errors are : change to getFragmentManager() or create method getSupportFragmentManager() But I have done both but not working. so please anybody help me. what need to change.

//ProjectOverview class

```
public class ProjectOverview extends Activity { 
    private PageAdapter mPageAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpages_layout);      
         initialingpaging();
    }   

     private void initialingpaging() {          
            List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment3.class.getName()));
            mPageAdapter = new PageAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);            
            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            pager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
        }
}
```

//  PageAdapter class

```
public final class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.fragments = fragments;     
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

//viewpages_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

//Fragment1.class

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(container == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout,container,false);
    }
}
```

//same code for Fragment2.class and Fragment3.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use getSupportFragmentManager extend your ProjectOverview with FragmentActivity. It will work, it is an issue with support library and yours fragments should be imported from support library.
*Added (checked):*
Your activity should extends `FragmentActivity` so you can use `getSupportFragmentManager()` (on older device) if you are targeting only newer device use (extend Activity): `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: When I added ProjectOverview with FragmentActivity still same problem comes.

Comment: Edited the answer check if it will help you